# Validation failed nodejs required field

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am creating creating a bookstore demo app in Node.js. I have ran into a little situation with the POST request for creating a genre. I've setup so the name of the genre must be required if not don't insert it to the database. But when I use Postman to POST to the url localhost:3000/api/genres with the JSON

```
{
  "name": "TEST"
}
```

It throws an error

```
{
  "error": "Genre validation failed"
}
```

When I remove the required field in the genreSchema it works but the name  of the genre doesn't appear. Here is my code

Code:

genre.js

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");


// Create a schema for genre
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var genreSchema = Schema({
    name:{ 
        type: String, 
        required: true 
    },
    create_date:{ 
        type: Date, 
        default: Date.now 
    }
});
var Genre = module.exports = mongoose.model("Genre", genreSchema);

// Methods

// get genres 
module.exports.getGenres = function(callback, limit) {
    Genre.find(callback).limit(limit);
};
// add a new genre
// TODO: Not working in Postman ValidationError
module.exports.addGenre = function(genre, callback) {
    Genre.create(genre, callback);
};
```

---

app.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Genre = require('./models/genre');
var Book = require('./models/book');
// Connect to mongoose
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/bookstore");
var db = mongoose.connection;

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.json({ error: "Please use /api/books or /api/genres" });
});

// GET /api/genres
app.get('/api/genres', function(req, res){
    Genre.getGenres(function(err, genres){
        if(err) {
            res.json({error: err.message})
        }
        res.json(genres);
    });
});
app.post('/api/genres', function(req, res){
    var genre = req.body;
    Genre.addGenre(genre, function(err, genre){
        if(err) {
            res.json({
                error: err.message
            })
        }
        res.json(genre);
    });
});
// GET /api/books
app.get('/api/books', function(req, res){
    Book.getBooks(function(err, books){
        if(err) {
            res.json({error: err.stack})
        }
        res.json(books);
    });
});
// GET /api/book/:id
app.get('/api/book/:_id', function(req, res){
    Book.getBookById(req.params._id, function(err, book){
        if(err) {
            res.json({error: err.message})
        }
        res.json(book);
    });
});


app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Running on port 3000!")
});
```

Comment: what's the value of `genre` in `Genre.addGenre` ? Are you sure you are getting the correct values?

Comment: Wait, I think I forgot to parse my JSON

Comment: Issue was because I didn't parse incoming json with body-parser module :P Stupid me. I knew I did everything right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `console.log(req.body);` inside your post route? I don't think you've setup body-parser as middleware so `req.body` is coming in empty and therefore not sending anything to your `Genre.addGenre` method.

Comment: As I just stated before this answer I noticed I did not parse the JSON :P